# Gson streaming API with different types of objects according to value of JSON field

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to parse the [Wikidata JSON dump](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download/en) using the Gson streaming API, since the file is around 70GB of json. The overall structure of the file is as follows:

```
[
{"type":"item",... other fields ...},
{"type":"property",... other fields ...},
.....
]
```

It is an array of objects in which each object can be of type `item` or `property` and I would like to instantiate a different class (namely I have a corresponding Item and Property class in my Java code) according to the object that I encounter.

Basically, I'd like to look at the `type` field and then parse the following JSON accordingly. Since the JsonReader doesn't seem to provide a `getNextJsonObject()` or similar function, is there a way to do this besides preprocessing the whole file and splitting the entries into two separate ones? The file is so big that I'd like to avoid the extra preprocessing step when I could do everything on the fly.

Comment: You should have access to `peek()` which will tell you what's coming up next.

Comment: I haven't found a way to make `peek()` work, because I have to peek until I find the `type` field and at that point I'm already inside the JSON object and can't go back

Comment: Can't you hold off on instantiating anything until you've seen the `type`?

Comment: Yes, but how do I instantiate it after? I have already read half of the object that is now gone (can't go back in the stream I suppose, saving what I already read seems too much of an hassle) and I have yet to read the other half

Comment: I don't know if what I say is making sense, but after reading half of the object, still without knowing if it's going to be an item or a property, and having to temporarily save the data and then merge it with what follows seems a very convoluted approach

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest. I don't think it's too much hassle. The only way to look forward is to save what you "skip". Maybe look at Jackson which has a polymorphic deserialization strategy that looks for the value of a property with `JsonTypeInfo`. It might be able to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Any idea why the JsonReader class doesn't provide a simple `getNextJsonObject()` function?

Comment: Nope. Might not fit the rest of the parsing style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a very easy solution after a bit of thinking. The Gson API provides the method:

```
Gson.fromJson(JsonReader reader, Class class)
```

This will read the next object from the reader and deserialize to the class you pass as parameter. Since in my case I don't know which class to serialize to I can do the following:

```
JsonObject asd = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class);
if (asd.get("type").getAsString().equals("item")) {
    // Instantiate item
} else {
    // Instantiate property
}
```